# Почему не возникает замыкания?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Я создаю массив, и хочу уменьшать все его элементы на один с каждым вызовом 
функции myReduceByOne(), помогите разобраться почему не работает через замыкание ?

```
var numb = [88,88,88,88,88];
function createReduce() {
    var arrBefore = numb;
    var reduceByOne = function() {
        return  arrBefore.map(function(item,i,arr) {
          return item-1;
        });
    } 
    return reduceByOne;
}
var myReduceByOne = createReduce();
console.log(myReduceByOne());
console.log(myReduceByOne());
console.log(myReduceByOne());
```

Comment: А причем тут замыкание ? Сама функция map не меняет исходного массива, вы возвращаете не тот массив, что получили на входе, а вновь созданный массив. Исходный массив не меняется

Comment: Вот если бы вы написали `return  arrBefore=arrBefore.map(....` то замыкание отработало бы как ему и положено, сохранив новый arrBefore между вызовами

Comment: @Mike я разбираюсь с замыканиями и придумал вот эту задачу, хотел сделать по аналогии с этой
var createCounter = function() {
 var counter = 0;
 var oneStepPlus = function() {
   return counter++;
 };
 return oneStepPlus;

}
var myCounter = createCounter();
console.log(myCounter()); // 0
console.log(myCounter()); // 1

Comment: @Mike Я знаю что задача решается и так (решение написал снизу), просто по аналогии с предыдущим кодом про counter (указал в комментарии выше), должна была сработать и та задача которая находится у меня в вопросе, за ваш ответ спасибо, но он не ответил на мой вопрос



var numb = [88,88,88,88,88];
var reduceByOne = function(arr) {
 return numb = numb.map(function(item) {
   return item-1;
 });
}
console.log(reduceByOne(numb));
console.log(reduceByOne(numb));

Comment: Операция `counter++` означает `counter=counter+1`. В примере с массивом у вас такого знака равенства, который бы изменил исходный массив нет. в примере с counter вы внутри замыкания меняете внешнюю переменную, а в примере с массивом не меняете и она остается прежней. при этом само замыкание работает, но мы этого не видим, потому что ничего не меняли

Comment: Спасибо @mike, только что понял благодаря вам !!!

Answer (score 0):

в коде по аналогии с которым вы пытаетесь сделать `counter++` означает, что исходный `counter` который находится в лексической области видимости замыкающей функции увеличивается на 1. В том коде который у вас в вопросе ничего подобного нет. Для того, что бы это работало, вам надо изменять `arrBefore`. То есть сначала присваивать, а потом возвращать:

```js
var numb = [88,88,88,88,88];
function createReduce() {
    var arrBefore = numb;
    var reduceByOne = function() {
        arrBefore = arrBefore.map(function(item,i,arr) {
          return item-1;
        });
        
        return arrBefore;
    } 
    return reduceByOne;
}
var myReduceByOne = createReduce();
console.log(myReduceByOne());
console.log(myReduceByOne());
console.log(myReduceByOne());
```

Comment: вопрос в том почему arrBefore не находится в лексической области видимости замыкающей функции ?) Мне не понятно, ведь функция  createReduce() завершилась и по идее мы не должны переписывать arrBefore = arrBefore.map(func ....., значения должны браться из замыкания

Comment: `arrBefore` находится в лексической области видимости, просто вы никак его не меняете ... `map()` лишь возвращает новый массив, но исходный не меняется, в то время как `counter++` именно МЕНЯЕТ `counter`.